# Jamsine throws error despite same code working in browser

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, document

I added this code to my component controller to focus an input and it worked great in the browser but it broke all of my template tests. I thought I could just flush the `$timeout` and all would be well but it's not.

```
vm.$onInit = init;

function init(){
    focusInput();
}

function focusInput(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $document[0]
            .querySelector('md-autocomplete-wrap')
            .querySelector('input')
            .focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

However, in my unit test Jasmine is reporting that `.querySelector` is not available because the result of the first `querySelector` is null in the test environment.

```
it('should render', function(){
    var wrap, searchBarDirective, $scope;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    searchBarDirective = $compile(angular.element(template))($scope);
    $scope.$digest(); 

    $timeout.flush();

    wrap = searchBarDirective.find('md-autocomplete-wrap')[0];
    expect(wrap).toBeDefined();
});
```

It's obvious to me that `$document` doesn't contain the rendered directive and thus the second `querySelector` fails. But why doesn't $document contain the directive?

I tried mocking querySelector with `spyOn($document[0], "querySelector").and.returnValues($document[0],$document[0])` but that doesn't get me past the `focus`. Thinking I have lot my way here.

*** Revised ***

I think that it is important to continue to use $document but I decided to drop the `querySelector` for the jqLite `find` method.

```
function focusInput(){
    $timeout(function(){
        var input;
        try {
            // can throw an error if the first find fails
            input = $document.find('md-autocomplete').find('input');
        }
        catch (e) {
            angular.noop(e);
        }
        if(input && angular.isFunction(input.focus)) {
            input.focus();
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

The test I changed per comments to below. I do have Karma load jquery to make testing easier which allows me to search for `:focus`

```
beforeEach(function(){
    element = angular.element(template);
    $document[0].body.appendChild(element[0]);
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
});
afterEach(function(){
    element[0].remove();
});
it('should be focused', function(){
    var input, searchBarDirective;
    searchBarDirective = $compile(element)($scope);

    $scope.$digest();
    $timeout.flush();

    input = searchBarDirective.find(':focus')[0];
    expect(input).toBeDefined();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your `querySelector` call works in the browser, but not in tests is that you are creating a DOM element with `angular.element`, but you are never attaching it to the document.  There are two ways to address this:

First, you could simply do this. Instead of:

```
searchBarDirective = $compile(angular.element(template))($scope);
```

Do:

```
let element; // declare this in the describe block so it is available later

element = angular.element(template);
document.body.appendChild(element[0]);
searchBarDirective = $compile(element)($scope);
```

And then do this:

```
afterEach(() => element[0].remove());
```

But, that's a bit messy. You should not be manipulating global scope (ie- the document) in your unit tests unless you have to.  It would be better in your non-test code to avoid accessing the document and instead access a scope element, or some other DOM element that you can also mock in your tests. This will be a bit harder to do since it may require re-architecting your code a bit. In general though, in order to make modular and testable code, you want to avoid accessing the `document` object as much as possible.

Comment: I've tried your example but I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null`

Comment: Does your template actually include the `md-autocomplete-wrap` and `input` element? Things would be much simpler if you could avoid calling querySelector directly on the document at all. Also, instead of calling querySelector twice, you'd be better off calling `.querySelector('md-autocomplete-wrap input')` in one go.